# TypeError: object of type '_io.BytesIO' has no len()

Tags: python

here is my code, i am trying to download a pdf url in my memory, then trying to open that in a 3rd party python package(PYmuPDF). But it is showing this error. How to solve this?

my code

```
    URL = "https://d2u493yfhe2l4v.cloudfront.net/1922/signed_contract/1922_signed_contract.pdf"
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    p = BytesIO(res.read())
    doc = fitz.open("pdf", p)
```

after this it gives such error, but as per documentation of fitz i think i have tried right! PymuPDF documentation about opening memory file 
https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document/

```
>>> # from memory
>>> doc = fitz.open("pdf", mem_area)
>>> doc = fitz.open(None, mem_area, "pdf")
>>> doc = fitz.open(stream = mem_area, filetype = "pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your version of PYmuPDF.

You missed the most important part of the documentation:
   --> "Changed in version 1.14.13: io.BytesIO is now also supported"

Alternatively, the following should work:

```
    URL = "https://d2u493yfhe2l4v.cloudfront.net/1922/signed_contract/1922_signed_contract.pdf"
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    p = bytearray(res.read())
    doc = fitz.open("pdf", p)
```